# How to remove obsolete packages after failed release upgrade via do-release-upgrade on Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, package-management, do-release-upgrade

Sometimes, when I upgrade a system via `do-release-upgrade`, the update process fails and the script tells me to finish the process manually via `dpkg --configure -a`. This is a not serious problem - after manually solving the dependencies problem and the finishing upgrade process all works well.

But the `do-release-upgrade` script has a cleanup process after finishing the upgrade:

```
Remove obsolete packages?  
XXX packages are going to be removed.  
Continue [yN]  Details [d]y
```

which removes some obsolete packages from old version of system.

Seems that this process doesn't execute when the automatic upgrade fails and I finish upgrade manually, so obsolete packages from old version remain installed in the system.

How I can run the "Remove obsolete packages" process manually after finishing the upgrade by hand?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Test this:

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).

Run this:

```sh
sudo -i

apt-get update
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
 
UNUSCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}')
apt-get remove --purge $UNUSCONF

NEWKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')

ADDKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"

METAKERNEL="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"

UNUSKERNELS=$(dpkg -l | awk '{print $2}' | grep -E $ADDKERNEL | grep -vE $METAKERNEL | grep -v $NEWKERNEL)

apt-get remove --purge $UNUSKERNELS

update-grub
```

Comment: Thanks, those commands is exactly that I want, main of them is `dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}'` that shows packages to remove. This is strange that apt-get or aptitude dont' want to see it for removing.

Comment: One-line cli command for remove obsolete packages after failed do-release-upgrade based on your example is: `sudo dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo apt-get remove -y --purge`. Attention, this command removes packages without confirmation, but is useful for automate quickly cleanup systems.

Comment: On my system the `'^rc'`-marked packages weren't even installed, but the upgrade failed right before searching for obsolete packages. So this answer seems incomplete. This won't remove _all_ packages which would be by `do-release-upgrade`, should it succeed.

Comment: Is this still valid in 2021? Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Answer (score 4):

Looking in the upgrade logs in `/var/log/dist-upgrade`, there is a line in `main.log`:

```
main.log:2020-12-23 21:01:53,154 DEBUG Obsolete: linux-headers-5.4.0-56-generic linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-56 linux-image-5.4.0-56-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-56-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-56-generic msgpack-tools slirp4netns
```

I *think* uninstalling these combined with the `apt-get autoremove` should do the same the upgrade would have done if it had run to completion.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "Remove obsolete packages" actually just runs a `sudo apt-get autoremove`. Try it, see if it helps.

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` is remove only little part of packages, that removes `do-release-upgrade`, for example `do-release-upgrade` on same system removes about 150 packages, but `apt-get autoremove` - remove only about 5-10 packages.

Answer (score 2):

I find that [this answer of an unrelated question](https://askubuntu.com/a/657204/109275) might provide a utility and command that seems to remove more of the unused stuff:

1. Install the "deborphan" package.
2. `sudo deborphan | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge`

Comment: note the difference between orphaned packages and obsolete packages. And that the OT wanted to remove obsolete packages - https://askubuntu.com/questions/286947/obsolete-packages-vs-orphaned-packages

Comment: @Daniel Alder the OT wanted to remove the obsolete packages after a failed release upgrade. What the release upgrade does as the final step after replacing the repositories and executing a full upgrade, is it removes orphaned packages. Therefore this is the last step to be repeated manually after a failed release upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

How to see all obsolete packages:

```sh
apt list '?obsolete'
```

How to remove all obsolete packages:

```sh
sudo apt -V remove '?obsolete'
```