# After upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, last process left cleaning, how to perform?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

While upgrading from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, every process got done like `Getting new packages`, `Installing upgrades`, the last process  was `Cleaning`. Now, my PC is running fine on 16.04 but while turning it on and shutting it down, it is showing to clean and giving errors. Due to electricity problem, cleaning process while upgrading didn't went well.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: (http://askubuntu.com/questions/657091/whats-the-good-way-to-clean-up-the-system-and-is-bleachbit-safe-on-ubuntu-14)

Answer (score 3):

I think the last cleaning process runs something like this:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

which removes any downloaded packages already installed, and this command:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

will remove any packages no longer in use like old kernels and the like.