# How to perform Cleaning process which left while upgrading from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

While upgrading from UBUNTU 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS, every process got done like Getting new packages, Installing upgrades, the last process LEFT that was CLEANING. Now, my pc is running fine on 16.04 but while turning it ON and shutting it down, it is showing to clean and giving errors. Due to electricity problem, cleaning process while upgrading didn't went well...

Please help and let me know, how can I fix this?  Because, I guess a single file will be there in two times in my system. Like there is two SOFTWARE CENTER in pc, older (from 14.04 LTS) and Newer (from 16.04 LTS)

Please give some command to do the left CLEANING process, which left while UPGRADING to 16.04 LtS

How can I do the cleaning process?

Plz tell the command and give the correct answers

Comment: Did you ask the same before? (http://askubuntu.com/questions/792604/after-upgrading-from-ubunbtu-14-04-lts-to-16-04-lts-last-process-left-cleaning)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`sudo apt-get clean` (is what cleans out unused package stuff. )

or/and

`sudo apt-get autoremove`  (will clean up any packages that are no longer needed.)