# How to delete Ubuntu files loaded on Vmware permanently to increase disk space c

Tags: vmware

When I delete a any program or file on Ubuntu, the C disk space does not increase on Windows 10. How can I delete unnecessary Ubuntu files to increase the disk space?

Comment: Your "c: drive" on Windows is not related to Ubuntu's files & folders. They are in separate partitions. If deleting files from a NTFS partition, you must have Windows fast start up off which is just hibernation & it has all the file info stored, so delete does not work. Turn fast start up off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions More explanation of NTFS driver & Windows hibernation
http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Resizing a VMWare disk is a host OS operation (so WIndows) https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2019649 Voting to leave closed.

Answer (score 0):

From a recent article (January 2018) you can make Ubuntu partition smaller and then give the free space to Windows. Here is the link to the full article: [How to Resize Ubuntu Partition Without data loss in Ubuntu & Windows?](http://www.eassos.com/blog/how-to-resize-ubuntu-partition-without-data-loss-in-ubuntu-windows/). The link has many steps complete with screen shots. There are two different methods in the link:

- Method 1: Change Ubuntu partition size using GParted with Linux.
- Method 2: Resize Ubuntu partition without data loss with Eassos PartitionGuru within Windows.

After making Ubuntu partition smaller, you can then expand the Windows partition to fill the void:

- [How to Expand or Extend Windows 7/Windows 8 Partition without Data Loss](https://www.easeus.com/partition-master/expand-windows-7-partition.html)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clear up two misunderstandings:

1. Your Windows files and Ubuntu files are stored on two separate partitions. The files on one are separate from the files on the other.
2. The size of the partitions are not governed by how much data they contain (inside files). In fact it's the opposite - you can only add as much data as the size of the partition.

---

For cleaning up space on Ubuntu, see [What's the good way to clean up the system (and is Bleachbit safe) on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/q/657091/301745)

From what I understand, you want to shrink the Ubuntu partition and grow the Windows partition. So, assuming your Ubuntu partition is immediately to the right of your Windows partition, you should just need to shrink it and move it to the right, then grow your Windows partition to fill the empty space. For details, see [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/301745)

Comment: I downloaded Ubuntu on VMware and the platform is Windows 10

Comment: @Mohammad OK, originally the question title said "besides Windows" which means dual-booting. Even after you edited the title, the question still sounds like it's about dual-booting, so please edit it to clarify.