# Ubuntu is slow after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

I had Ubuntu 16.04.. LTS and it was working perfectly but after upgrading to 18.04.1 LTS It is really slow, it hangs randomly.

Here is my Laptop Details:
[image: My PC Details]

Here is my Ram USAGE

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3854        2365         583         403         905         852
Swap:          4004          18        3986
```

Comment: Before you do anything else, try to clean your system, here's a question where you can find links about how to do it properly... hope it helps... https://askubuntu.com/questions/657091/whats-the-good-way-to-clean-up-the-system-and-is-bleachbit-safe-on-ubuntu-14

Comment: most probably cause you have only 4 gigs of ram. Ubuntu 18 comes with gnome shell which itself eats about 1.2gig ram, let alone other app.

Comment: @ft18, I have cleaned it twice

Comment: @SirajusSalekin What alternative is good?

Comment: @ArsalanKhattak, you can always go back to 16.04, but if you need 18.04 (for using steamplay and newer graphics support) you can use low resource flavors like ubuntu mate, xubuntu or lubuntu . All of them have memory usage below 500mb on idle.

Comment: @SirajusSalekin Is there any way to downgrade ? or I have to manually install 16.04 ?

Comment: You may want to switch to other desktop environment: Unity - from `ubuntu-unity-desktop` package or MATE from `ubuntu-mate-desktop` to save some resources and make your workspace more productive. I can use MATE even on 2 Gb of RAM (with 3-5 tabs in Firefox and LibreOffice opened).