# Upgrading impaired by full partition (having only 2 kernels). Is partitioning the only solution?

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, kernel, 18.10, resize

*Not enough space in disk* seems to be a common problem while upgrading. My upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10 (in order to eventually go to 19.04) fails because I need 1050 Mb more than available, which I cannot free by erasing kernels.

I've tried `sudo apt autoclean` and `autoremove`; also I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot), but I don't have a lot of installed kernels, just:

```
linux-headers-4.15.0-48
linux-headers-4.15.0-48-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-48-generic
```

Altogether, if purged, I'd free only about 200 Mb (not enough to upgrade).
The upgrade would be implemented in partition `/dev/sda6` named `/`:

[image]

Is resizing the partition the only (painful) solution?

Or how can I let the upgrade in other partition? How could I see what I have in that partition other than that kernel?

Comment: The recommended partition size is 25gb so I'd recommend increasing size so you're less likely to have to go through this again in the move to 19.10 etc. In the past I've moved data (directories) from / to another partition (eg. moved to a directory in your /home; then changed fstab so it mounts the directory in the correct place) but it wasn't fun so I'd not recommend it if you can't see what I mean from this description. I'd recommend resizing to give yourself room, or just re-install [something-else, no format] is far easier/faster, can skip 18.10; and re-adds back your added repo programs)

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably do the latter. :)

Comment: Just resize and move sda7 and then resize sda6.

Comment: Your swap partition is also too small.

Comment: If upgrading, you may have many old obsolete files that should be housecleaned. Kernels from previous versions, old log files and other "stuff". Older, but still valid: https://askubuntu.com/questions/657091/whats-the-good-way-to-clean-up-the-system-and-is-bleachbit-safe-on-ubuntu-14

Comment: I also cleaned orphaned ones, but still not enough space.