# System Information Startup Script

Tags: server

I am Using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

my question is about I was looking at my system information startup script and i saw something named

> Usage of /: 88.5% of 3.87GB

i have no idea what it is i checked my ram and saw only 22% of it is getting used  so its not ram i have already checked all the system info with other scripts its not ram not cpu not my ssd i really dont know what it is

Its good to note that this server is being used as a vpn endpoint i just its good to state that

Thanks For Answers

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed disk usage. It shows that the partition mounted on `/` is of size 3.87 GB and is 88.5% full. Try running `df -h` to confirm the output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you are right do you know why its filling up by day or how to reduce it or what is filling it up

Comment: 3.87 GB is a really unacceptable size for a root partition. I would suggest you to increase the size of the partition if possible. If that is not an option, I suggest [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657091/whats-the-good-way-to-clean-up-the-system-and-is-bleachbit-safe-on-ubuntu-14)

Comment: yes i should probably do that thanks for the help i asked all my university teachers and all of them were clueless