# How to clean up deprecated packages after a failed Lubuntu or Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, lubuntu

I tried upgraded my Lubuntu 18.10 system to 19.04 using the standard GUI which runs the `do-release-upgrade` command. It got most of the way through the installation, installing all the packages. However, it failed before making it to the clean-up section. This has resulted in an unfortunate problem where many of the applications that were deprecated are installed alongside their replacements.

This is obvious when looking at the system tray:
[image: System Tray]

You can see two network tray icons (for two different program instances) and two power icons. In the applications menu, there are many sets of duplicate programs, i.e. two "Additional Drivers".

My question is how can I remove these deprecated applications from my system? Is there a simple command I can run? If I have to remove each one individually, how can I know which ones were deprecated and which ones are current?

[In case anyone thinks to suggest it, I've already worked through this answer and it doesn't solve my problem.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539235/how-to-remove-obsolete-packages-after-failed-release-upgrade-via-do-release-upgr#)

Comment: Have you tried this: `To remove an item from quick launch right click on the icon and select Remove from quicklaunch.`  https://manual.lubuntu.me/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html

Comment: My goal isn't to remove items from the quick launch, but to remove deprecated packages that were not removed in the failed upgrade from Lubuntu 18.10 to 19.04.

Comment: have you tried `apt autoremove` ? Notice that an icon can stay on the menu while the package is gone. So you probably need to remove them manually anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have tried, and the packages are definitely still there. Example: `ps aux | grep nm-` outputs two processes, `nm-applet` & `nm-tray`. If I kill the `nm-applet` process, that icon disappears. They both do the exact same thing, but I believe the `nm-applet` is from the older distro version.

Answer (score 1):

Install if possible `sudo apt install apt-show-versions`

```
apt-show-versions | grep 'No available'
```

lists packages which no longer available in your package source. Take a good look which one you maybe need. You can remove them all together with `sudo apt  purge $(apt-show-versions | grep 'No available' | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: Thank- I gave this a try and it identified a few deprecated packages, but it doesn't look like it worked for the vast majority (my system tray still looks the same and still lots of duplicate entries in the application menu).

Comment: I unterstood you want get rid of no more available packages.