# Remove all non-existent repositories in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, command-line, add-apt-repository

How do I remove all repositories which don’t exist for one reason or another? I am wondering if there is a command to do this, so that I can remove all such repositories at once. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What is your definition of "don't exist"?  I would assume a PPA you added does exist?

Comment: "Non-existant"? You mean ones that either never existed or have been shutdown and actually take down?

Comment: I think he means those repos that might have been active but are no more active. I think he wants to "clean up" the repo list

Comment: Perhaps looking for orphaned or obsolete packages? https://askubuntu.com/questions/286947/obsolete-packages-vs-orphaned-packages