# Why are android-tools-adb and android-tools-fastboot packages marked as orphan?

Tags: package-management, android-sdk

I'm using **gtkorphan 0.4.4** to get rid of some unused packages. 
The following are listed as orphan even if I installed them manually:

```
android-tools-adb
android-tools-fastboot
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The impression I get from reading https://askubuntu.com/a/287766/768583 is that it seems they may of been linked to another package/metapackage at one point on your system that has since been removed so they appear as orphaned, hope that helps in some way, sorry I can't be of more assistance.